# How to create a new row in tag_facets()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, facet

In the first facet of the graph, I have a caption in the top corner that says, "this is interesting what now" but I would like it to show up as:

```
this is interesting
what now
```

Every time I put in `\n` I would like a new line, but I'm not sure how to do it in the context of `tag_facets()`.

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
# devtools::install_github("eliocamp/tagger")
library(tagger)


ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width") +
  tag_facets(
    tag_pool = c("this is interesting\nwhat now", "for what:\nnow", "hey:\nhow are you?"),
    tag_suffix = "",
    position = "tr") +
  theme(tagger.panel.tag.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `tagger` uses `gridtext::richtext_grob` under the hood which allows for formatting via HTML, CSS and markdown but requires to use `<br>` instead of `\n` to add line breaks:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tagger)

tag_pool <- c("this is interesting\nwhat now", "for what:\nnow", "hey:\nhow are you?")
tag_pool <- gsub("\\n", "<br>", tag_pool)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape = Species)) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width") +
  tag_facets(
    tag_pool = tag_pool,
    tag_suffix = "",
    position = "tr"
  ) +
  theme(tagger.panel.tag.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: This is fabulous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width") +
  facet_wrap(~Species)+ 
  geom_label(data = data.frame(x = 6, y = 5, Species = "setosa", 
                              label = "this is interesting\nwhat now"), 
                                  aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), size = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but certainly helpful for future graphs! Thanks!